# restfb: get page picture

Tags: facebook-graph-api, grails, groovy, restfb

I am trying to get the Page picture. However it always comes back as null. Am i doing something wrong?

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken)
def page = facebookClient.fetchObject(PAGE_ID, Page.class);
println page.picture //prints null
```

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the accessToken with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly ask for the fields you're interested (otherwise everything is `null`). In your case, you want the **`picture`**:

```
facebookClient.fetchObject(PAGE_ID, Page.class, Parameter.with("fields", "picture"));
```

For all fields, check [official page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should have getPicture instead of picture. Also some pages require you to be logged in to retrieve that information. So you might need to authenticate with an access token.

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken)
def page = facebookClient.fetchObject(PAGE_ID, Page.class);
println page.getPicture //prints null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(facebookAccessToken, Version.LATEST);

JsonObject jsonObject = facebookClient.fetchObject("/" + userId + "/picture", JsonObject.class,
        Parameter.with("type", "large"), Parameter.with("redirect", "false"));
JsonValue jsonValue = jsonObject.get("data");
JsonObject object = jsonValue.asObject();
String profileImageUrl = object.get("url").asString();
```